# Is there a secure way to send a passport from the Netherlands to Spain?

Tags: netherlands, passport, spain

I want to send my passport to our embassy in Madrid. I live in the Netherlands. What are my options?

PostNL? is it safe to send the passport using it?

Comment: When you say 'our' embassy, to which country are you referring? If it's the country indicated in your profile, have you considering asking your embassy/consulate in the Netherlands whether it would send it via its secure courier system?

Comment: Define "secure".

Comment: DHL is one of the common ways of sending documents. They have special courier service for that.

Comment: @Dorothy I'm Syrian, and we don't have embassy in the Netherlands

Comment: @fkraiem I mean no lost and no damage

Comment: I am not convinced courier services are *per se* more secure. What they offer is more speed. I have had documents stolen that way and heard about widespread problems at one point in the press. I would go for regular certified mail (*aangetekend*). It implies special handling and tracking and comes with an insurance but even that isn't an ironclad guarantee obviously.

Comment: It is probably worth checking in the Spanish embassy itself to see if they can do the transport through diplomatic means.

Comment: @EugenMartynov +1 make your comment an answer, and I'll upvote,
 and here's a [DHL link](http://www.dhl-usa.com/en/express.html)

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar situation when there was no Canadian embassy in Netherlands.

So the nearest was in UK or Austria. And on their website was clear instruction how to send and receive the passport with DHL.

DHL courier service [allows](https://parcel.dhl.co.uk/what-you-can-and-cant-send) you to send passports.

I also know that in Ukraine TNT was responsible for delivering passports within the country. Looks like they [also ship documents](https://www.tnt.com/express/en_gc/site/shipping-services/special-services.html).

I would call your embassy and ask if they have preferred solution. If not I would propose them variant with your preference.