# How to pay in advance to the returning passport that was sent to the embassy?

Tags: netherlands, passport, spain

[As my previous question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11847/is-there-a-secure-way-to-send-a-passport-from-the-netherlands-to-spain), there are two options to send my passport from the Netherlands to our embassy (The Syrian embassy) in Spain, which are:

1. PostNL: There's a special service for valuable things including passports
2. DHL: there is DHL express to send passports

My embassy will send me the passport back after 30 days, and they want me to pay in advance to the returning packet. However, neither PostNL, nor DHL offers such a service

So my question is how to pay in advance for the returning packet? Any suggestions?

P.S. I already suggested to send them in advance the cost of the returning packet, but that's not an option for them

Comment: Maybe http://www.dhl.nl/en/express/shipping/ship_online/ereturn.html

Comment: @EugenMartynov again, spot on; add and I'll upvote +1

Answer (score 1):

At least [DHL has returning shipment](http://www.dhl.nl/en/express/shipping/ship_online/ereturn.html) where you can up front put instructions, print labels and pay.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure if this service applies for individuals. Because on [their website](https://www.mydhl.dhl.com/mydhl/appmanager/smep/customerDesktop?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=smep_portal_page_login&utm_source=NL&utm_medium=hp_tc&utm_campaign=login_link), when I try to [register](https://www.mydhl.dhl.com/mydhl/appmanager/smep/customerDesktop?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=smep_portal_page_userregistration&_nfls=false), they ask me about the company's name. Can you double check please?

Comment: I see that it has [commercial purposes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8oKOF2bxyc)